# Mongoose: Displaying data with ObjectID (or populate)

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mern, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am writing a MERN web application. This particular page is focused on recording demerits that have been accrued by students. I have many different models that interact with each other, but in this case I need the following to interact:

```
const demeritReportInstanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
...
})
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
    fName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
...
})
```

whereas when the table is displayed, it currently looks like this:

| user | offenseDate | period | infractionCode | punishingOfficial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (this is a user ObjectID) *65c5480f6b1bcdbcee2491aa* | Feb 2, 2024 | 1 | *another objectID* | *another user ObjectID* |

I need it it look like:

| user | offenseDate | period | infractionCode | punishingOfficial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lName, fName | Feb 2, 2024 | 1 | M11012 | lName, fName |

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvCiNeLnZ00&t=12778s&ab_channel=DaveGray (ref: chapter 7) in which Dave has a Note and User model (backend) like the following:

```
const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
...
})
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})
```

that displays the username in a similar table as what I have (frontend) by:

Note.js

```
        return (
            <tr className="table__row">
                ...
                <td className="table__cell note__username">{note.username}</td>

                ...
            </tr>
        )
```

NotesList.js

```
    if (isSuccess) {
        const { ids } = notes

        const tableContent = ids?.length
            ? ids.map(noteId => <Note key={noteId} noteId={noteId} />)
            : null

        content = (
            <table className="table table--notes">
                <thead className="table__thead">
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <th scope="col" className="table__th note__username">Owner</th>
                    ...
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {tableContent}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using {demerit.user} provides me with the ID of the user as displayed above. Using {demerit.user.fName}, {demerit.user.lName} provides me with " , " in the cell of the table, and does not return its attributes.
I have been examining how to use Model.populate from Mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html but I do not know where I would place populating queries - in the frontend, or the backend with the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this easy for you implement, I have had a look at the tutorial and the author seems to be importing the models into a controller and making custom query functions to the database then using them inside each route handler. Therefore following the pattern adopted in the tutorial your code might look something like:

```js
const Demerits = require('../models/Demerits'); //< or whatever this model is called
const User = require('../models/User');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');

const getAllDemerits = asyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
   const demerits = await Demerits.find().populate('user').lean();
   if(!demerits){
      return res.status(400).json({message: 'No demerits found'});
   }
   res.json(demerits);
})
```

Here `populate('user')` is what swaps the `ObjectId` for the full `User` documents and will allow you to access `user.fName` and `user.lName` in your front-end.

Comment: This worked! For anyone reading this, following the tutorial, I have controllers on my backend for my demerit object, and I used this for all of the models that interact with demerits, such as punishingOfficial from type User and code from type Infraction. It now populates completely by stringing the .populate('user').populate('code').populate('punishingOfficial').lean() ... thank you!